# jquery val() with Eric Martin's simple modal form

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I have an issue with getting a text field value while using the Simple Modal form by Eric Martin. The `$('#pcs_'+id).val();` seems to return nothing (variable _t below is undefined).

The HTML part that is generated in the 'pop up' modal form:

```
<form><input type="text" id="pcs_25" value="1"> pcs </form> 
<a id="add_basket_25" onclick="return add2Basket(25);" class="button basket_list options_true" href="/emarket/basket/put/element/25/">add to basket</a>
```

The JS part:

```
function add2Basket(id){

    var _t = $('#pcs_'+id).val(); 
    _t = $.trim(_t); 

    var rege = /^[\d]{1,}$/;    // numbers 
    if(rege.test(_t)){          //do something 
        var add2cartlink = $('#add_basket_'+id).attr('href'); 
        add2cartlink += _t; 
        // window.location.href = add2cartlink;
        return false;
    }  
    else {
        alert("Only numbers allowed!"); 
        return false;           
    }
}
```

Note that this works fine beyond the modal form, and only brings up an issue if within the Modal form container.

Has anyone encountered such thing in the past?

**Added**: If called explicitly ,  such as `$('#pcs_25').val()` or `$('#pcs_25').attr('value')`, the returned is the value hard-coded into the HTML part, that is `<input type="text" id="pcs_25" value="1">`. It seems to ignore the values entered manually into the text field .

**Solved:** I should have guessed before that Simple Modal copies the form's input text field into the resulting html, so there were actually 2 `id='pcs_25'` elements in the resulting html page. So the jquery selector required more precision.  `$('.simplemodal-data #pcs_'+id).val()` solved the issue.

Comment: Try making an explicit call, changing var _t = var _t = $('#pcs_25').val(); and var add2cartlink = $('#add_basket_25').attr('href'); what are the results?

Comment: try to simplify the Javascript

Comment: Why hard-code the ID's at all, if you could traverse to the previous or next element?

Answer (score 0):

For the following html, I could get the following to work:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="pcs_25" value="1"> pcs  
<a id="add_basket_25" class="button basket_list options_true" href="/emarket/basket/put/element/25/">add to basket</a>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="pcs_26" value="1"> pcs  
<a id="add_basket_26" class="button basket_list options_true" href="/emarket/basket/put/element/26/">add to basket</a>

</form>​
```

with the following simplified JavaScript, you can develop without needing any regex:

```
jQuery(".button.basket_list").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault(); //stops the click from going through
    //alert(jQuery(this).prev().val());
    var amountToAdd = parseInt(jQuery(this).prev().val()); //the parseint function will sometimes strip non numeric values off from the end of the text value
    alert(amountToAdd);
    if (amountToAdd) {
            //window.location.href = jQuery(this).attr('href'); //If we still need to go somewhere
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Only numbers allowed!");
    }
});
```

This simply selects the text box element before the anchor element, and work with it's values.

See Sample here at:
http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/Lbxj6/9/

If you do not want to work that way, then add rel="25" to the hyper link, and use it as I did in the following example.
http://jsfiddle.net/webwarrior/L6PN5/3/

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="pcs_25" value="1"> pcs  
<a id="add_basket_25" class="button basket_list options_true" href="/emarket/basket/put/element/25/" rel="25">add to basket</a>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" id="pcs_26" value="1"> pcs  
<a id="add_basket_26" class="button basket_list options_true" href="/emarket/basket/put/element/26/" rel="26">add to basket</a>

</form>
```

and the javascript:

```
jQuery(".button.basket_list").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault(); //stops the click from going through
    //alert(jQuery(this).prev().val());
    var ID = jQuery(this).attr('rel');
    var amountToAdd = parseInt(jQuery(".simplemodal-data #pcs_" + ID).val()); //the parseint function will sometimes strip non numeric values off from the end of the text value
    alert(amountToAdd);
    if (amountToAdd) {
            //window.location.href = jQuery(this).attr('href'); //If we still need to go somewhere
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Only numbers allowed!");
    }
});​
```

hth

Comment: the problem is not with the reg-exp, it is somewhere with the selector, so jQuery("#pcs_" + ID).val() won't work in either version, yours or mine.

Comment: I do not understand! My version gave me the correct return every time. Unless you explicitly need to report that a value is not numeric, when there is a single character not numeric. I am a strong believer of just stripping the garbage out, use what I can, and get on with it. People do make mistakes, and we should try to help them, not annoy them